# Open a file in an Eclipse PDE View

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

I have created an Eclipse PDE view, called SampleView. Currently, to programmatically display the output from my file on the view, I am consuming each line from the file, and printing to the view using a scanner. **Is this the best way to display the file data? Or is there a better, existing function that I can use in my code to open the file in the view?**

**Code for SampleView:**

```
public class SampleView extends ViewPart {

    /**
     * The ID of the view as specified by the extension.
     */
    public static final String ID = "asher.views.id.SampleView";

    @Inject IWorkbench workbench;


     

    @Override
    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
        
        Text text = new Text(parent, SWT.READ_ONLY | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);
        
         File file = new File("/Users/user/Desktop/untitled.json");
         Scanner sc;
        
        try {
            sc = new Scanner(file);
            while (sc.hasNextLine()) 
                  text.setText(text.getText()+"\n"+sc.nextLine()); 
            sc.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setFocus() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of reading using a `Scanner`, I'd recommend the cleaner approach described here: [How can I read a large text file line by line using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868369/how-can-i-read-a-large-text-file-line-by-line-using-java)

I'd also recommend not repeatedly calling `setText` and simply appending on the current text; instead, use a `StringBuilder` and simply call `setText` with the result of the `StringBuilder`.

All together, it would look something like this:

```java
public class SampleView extends ViewPart {

    /**
     * The ID of the view as specified by the extension.
     */
    public static final String ID = "asher.views.id.SampleView";

    @Inject IWorkbench workbench;  

    @Override
    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
        Text text = new Text(parent, SWT.READ_ONLY | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("");
        try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get("/Users/user/Desktop/untitled.json"));) {
            stream.forEach(line -> builder.append(line).append("\n"));
            text.setText(builder.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setFocus() {
    }
}
```

Comment: `Files.lines` returns a stream which must be closed (unlike most streams) so it should be in a 'try-with-resources'. Your current code leaves the file open.

Comment: Thanks @greg-449!  It even points that out on the post I had linked but I glossed over it.